# Do I need to setup nginx as a reverse proxy for my MongoDB instance?

Tags: mongodb, nginx, proxy

I have configured nginx as a reverse proxy for my webapp like this:

```
https://www.myapp.com - main site
https://api.myapp.com - api endpoints
```

I wonder, if I should run mongodb independently of nginx environment or I can configure it so that it is accessible on this route:

```
https://db.myapp.com - mongodb running here
```

Is it a viable option or I shouldn't care about how elegant the url is and just use a standard config like described in [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)? If I go this way, will there be any performance issues linked with this config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely do not need Nginx for that. MongoDB has a custom load balancer/reverse proxy ([mongos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongos/)) that you can employ once you move to a sharded and replicated MongoDB cluster.

If your idea was to expose MongoDB publicly via Nginx you should have a look at Backend-as-a-Service solutions like deployd or Meteor. A public facing MongoDB without any additional security measure and an API layer would otherwise be highly insecure.

If you just want to have a different host name for MongoDB you should use your DNS server or service (e.g. Route53 if you are on AWS) to map the server IP to a memorable name.